# Ember Tests Page Returns 404 Error

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I'm trying to add unit tests to an existing project that was developed over the last two years and updated regularly to newest ember version.

To do that, I started by running

```
$ ember test -s
version: 1.13.13
Building...

Build successful - 11946ms.
```

The process is started, but then the web browser opens and I get the following error message in the browser window:

```
Not found: /7596/tests/index.html?hidepassed
```

The number changes, but I can remove it to get the same result. Accessing `/` just redirects to `/tests/index.html?hidepassed`, with the same result.

Here's the output of `curl`:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:7357/tests/index.html?hidepassed
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Cache-Control: No-cache
Pragma: No-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 39
ETag: W/"27-KHWxXB+A/SkhyzCtPXoJ4Q"
Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 16:41:22 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Not found: /tests/index.html?hidepassed
```

When the unit test server is not running, the port is closed, so it appears to be the right web server and not something else on my system.

When I create a new project with ember-cli the test page works fine. I have compared all files in the `tests` directory, `testem.json`, `ember-cli-build.js`, `bower.json` and `package.json`, but I'm unable to locate any difference that could cause this issue.

Does anybody have an idea what I could look for to get this working with my existing project?

I'm running ember 2.2.0 and ember-cli 1.13.13. If it makes any difference, the ember project usually is run through `ember-cli-rails-addon`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else has the same issue: in `ember-cli-build.js`, I had `tests` set to false on the EmberApp constructor options hash. This caused the tests directory to not be included in the build product, thus generating a 404.